# division of two matrices with different domination in python

Tags: python, matlab, matrix, divide

I'm trying to divide a matrix (4**4) over a matrix(4*1) such as:

```py
A= np.array([[4.76169807e-07,0,0,0],
             [0,4.76211146e-07,0,0],
             [0,0,1.86128889e-06, 0],
             [0,0,0,1.88126161e-06]])

B=np.array([[3.95],[ 2.35],[2.35],[2.35]])

C=np.divide(A,B)
```

In Matlab I use `C= A/B` and the answer is a matrix(4*1)

```matlab
C=
 [1.0e+06 *
  8.295360054732532
   8.294639966113035
   1.262565964938776
   1.249161724594699]
```

but in python is totally different and answer is a matrix (4*4)

```py
C= [[1.20549318e-07 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00]
 [0.00000000e+00 2.02643041e-07 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00]
 [0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 7.92037826e-07 0.00000000e+00]
 [0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 8.00536855e-07]]
```

How can get the correct answer in python such as matlab?

Comment: Did you mean `C = B/A`?

Comment: @parnavHosangadi  no, I mean `C=A/B`, still, the answer is not correct even use `C=B/A`  the answer is a matrix (4**4 )

Comment: The numbers you show in `C` don't make sense for `C = A/B`. `4.76169807e-07`  divided by `3.95` is not `1.0e+06 * 8.295360054732532`. However, `B / A` or `3.95/4.76169807e-07` _is_ equal to what you show in `C`, but you'd need `B` to be a row-vector for that to work and your python code shows that it's a column vector

Answer (score 1):

The operation `C=B/A` is not well defined because matrix multiplication is not commutative (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/228229/is-division-of-matrices-possible)), so it can help to frame your problem in terms of matrix multiplication instead of division. That being said: Your MATLAB output appears to be the diagonal elements of matrix A divided element-wise by the by the elements of vector B.

In order to get this same behavior in python you will need to use

```
A= np.array([[4.76169807e-07,0,0,0], [0,4.76211146e-07,0,0], 
[0,0,1.86128889e-06, 0], [0,0,0,1.88126161e-06]])
A = np.diag(A)
B = np.array([3.95,2.35,2.35,2.35])
C = np.divide(B, A)
```

Now we have the desired value in `C`:

```
array([ 8295360.06259213, 
        4934785.79772679,
        1262565.96309453,
        1249161.72610358])
```

Comment: Dear Isaac, thank you for your answer, but still it's not working and the answer in python exist as:  [[1.20549318e-07 1.20559784e-07 4.71212377e-07 4.76268763e-07]
 [1.20549318e-07 1.20559784e-07 4.71212377e-07 4.76268763e-07]
 [2.02625450e-07 2.02643041e-07 7.92037824e-07 8.00536856e-07]
 [2.02625450e-07 2.02643041e-07 7.92037824e-07 8.00536856e-07]]

should find another way !!!!!

Comment: no, I mean `C=A/B`, still, the answer is not correct even use `C=B/A`  the answer is a matrix (4**4 )